# How to reduce nested data in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

Say my state is

```
{
taskGroups: [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Shopping list",
    list: [
        {id: 0, name: "Milk", done: false},
        {id: 1, name: "Eggs", done: true},
        {id: 2, name: "Bean bag", done: true}
    ]
},
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Hit list",
        list: [
            {id: 0, name: "Vinoj", done: false},
            {id: 1, name: "Sandeep", done: true},
            {id: 2, name: "Amala", done: true},
            {id: 3, name: "Dixy", done: true},
            {id: 4, name: "Ajay", done: true},
            {id: 5, name: "Ashwin", done: true},
            {id: 6, name: "Yashin", done: true},
            {id: 7, name: "Mudassir", done: true},
            {id: 8, name: "Ishan", done: true}
        ]
    }
],
searchText: ""};
```

Say I want to update the name of an item in the list of one of the task groups using the action:

```
 updateListItem(text, taskGroupId, listItemId){
    return { type: 'UPDATE_LIST_ITEM', text, taskGroupId, listItemId};
}
```

My root reducer:

```
export function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

    case 'UPDATE_LIST_ITEM':
        return {
            taskGroups: state.taskGroups.map(taskGroup => {
                if (taskGroup.id === action.taskGroupId)
                    return {
                        ...taskGroup,
                        list: taskGroupListReducer(taskGroup.list, action)
                    };
                else  return taskGroup;
            }),
            searchText: state.searchText
        };
        //other cases
}
```

Task group list reducer:

```
function taskGroupListReducer(list = [], action) {
      case "UPDATE_LIST_ITEM":
        return list.map(item => {
            if (item.id === action.listItemId)
                return {...item, name: action.text};
            return item;
        });
    //other cases
}
```

Here I'm using `map` on the list array. Because of the way I've implemented search, I cannot use index of the list item as it will break or else I could have used slice.
If I don't use normalized data ([normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr)), how else can this be achieved without using map (which goes through each item)?

Comment: Without using Normalizr I don't see how you can make it any different. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan Just wanted to know how other people are doing it

Comment: You can spare the `if` if you use the IDs as indexes in the list.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan When search feature is used, taskGroups and their lists will be filtered in the view but reducer will act upon the unfiltered store and hence can't use indexes.

Comment: @ArjunU. This is pretty hard to accomplish with vanilla javascript but there are some nice libraries that makes updating nested structures way simpler.

Have look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/. 
They provide deeply nested update helpers aswell as finder methods to grab just the list item with the ID you provide.

Have a look at updateIn(). https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn
Hope this helps!